# Oracle Parametized Query with RAW type

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I am having a problem obtaining values from my Oracle 10g database when I attempt to complete a query on an Oracle RAW type. The myrawhash is originally a string. Perhaps I'm not converting this correctly.

```
cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable where HASH = :myrawhash";
cmd.Connection = oconn;

OracleParameter p_md5hash = new OracleParameter(":myrawhash", OracleType.Raw, 32);
// I suspect the line below is incorrect:                            
p_md5hash.Value = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myrawhash);  
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_md5hash);
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
```

ERROR I'm getting from the exeception:
   ** No data exists for the row or column.

I know this exists in the database.  Thoughts?

Comment: `if(dr.Read())` then do something. I guess your query doesn't return any data.